# Getting "Cross origin request error" when using 'LoadURL()' from Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I got this code from this article:
http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-mapbox/

code:

```
var filterLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.loadURL('data.geojson')
.addTo(map);
```

I'm trying to follow this Mapbox.js example that creates filters for placemarkers:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/

When I copy the entire example, I don't see any placemarkers at all, like the example in the link above. So I decided to load my own geoJson file.

Therefore I used the code I typed here earlier to load my own geoJson file. But I get this error when I inspect element:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/website/data.geojson. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,    
chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serve your `data.geojson` from local HTTP server instead of using `file://` protocol.

For example you can use WAMP server and copy contents of `spike321.github.io` directory to WAMP public html path.

Then you can open `localhost/spike321.github.io` and everything should work.